# Как правильно построить предложение - "доведены до сведения в службу" или [...]?

Tags: синтаксис

Как правильно построить предложение?
"все вышеуказанные проблемы доведены до сведения в службу технической поддержки"
или
"все вышеуказанные проблемы доведены до сведения службы технической поддержки"?
По моему мнению корректнее куда, значит в службу. Или я не прав?

Comment: У службы нет сведения, это используется, когда субъект, а не объект.

Comment: @oleedd, т.е. оба варианта неверные? Тогда как корректнее составить данное предложение?

Comment: Надо переформулировать, например: *Служба технической поддержки уведомлена о всех вышеуказанных проблемах.*